# Show that the fibers of $f$ are in bijective correspondence with the points in the range of $f$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:ℝ→ℝ$ be a real analytic function. Let $a∈ℝ$, we know that the fiber $f^{-1}(a)$ is a discrete set unless $f$ is constant. My question is: Show that the fibers of $f$ are in bijective correspondence with the points in the range of $f$.

Comment: What is there to be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is a very general concept. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a map between sets $X$ and $Y$. Then the map
$$ f(X) \rightarrow \{f^{-1}(\{a\}) \:|\: a \in f(X)\}, a \mapsto f^{-1}(\{a\})$$
is a bijection. Surjectivity is clear and noting that $f^{-1}(\{a\}) = f^{-1}(\{b\})$ for some $a,b \in f(X)$ implies $a = b$ shows the injectivity.